# Retrieve documents from CouchDB based on unique field

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchdbkit

How can I retrieve document from CouchDB based on its field, not by ID?

The problem is, documents in my system should have numeric IDs, so I add a field called `doc_id` to saved documents. Native CouchDB ids are too long for me.

How can I retrieve document with `doc_id` = 10, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve the document(s) with `doc_id`=10, you need to create a view with `doc_id` as a key. Afair, you cannot enforce uniqueness of the `doc_id`.

Instead of using your `doc_id`, you could still use CouchDB's `_id` field. Iirc, you do not have to leave it to CouchDB to assign a value to `_id`. If you do not like the UUIDs CouchDB uses for the `_id` field, you can create a document with an `_id` you specify.

You need to be careful with that, esp. in a distributed setup. If you end up with different documents (on different nodes) having the same `_id`, CouchDB might consider them to be different versions of the same document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) The connector I'm using seems to have problem with views, but I'll try this thing with custom IDs.

Comment: Documents with the same `_id` **are** different versions of the same document.